# Add border to expanded div after height changes from ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Thanks in advance for any advice - 
I have a table with a bunch of tbody's as the rows.
Each tbody can be expanded either seperately or all together.
I am adding a border around the expanded tbody through a border class
There are also 2 levels of expansion - so the border class is added when either one is showing.

I have a simple function:

```
    function toggleBorder(el){ 
        if($(el).height() > 50){
            $(el).addClass('tbodyBorder');
        }else{
          $(el).removeClass('tbodyBorder');
       }
    }
```

(BTW: the reason I'm checking the height is because the click events I'm piggy-backing on are toggle functions so I minimize the need to create a new click event.)

This function could be triggered 4 different ways. 2 of these use ajax to get the data to show in the expanded section so I put the toggleBorder() inside a setTimeout function which works fine for when I expand a single row,

but - Here's my Question:

For when I want to expand all the rows, it could take X amount of time for the server to return all the data and populate the rows and if it checks before the data is loaded, the height will not have changed thereby not adding the border Class and I keep making the setTimeout longer which is ridiculious for when I have one row.....

Any ideas.... thinking about setInterval but seems like over kill....

Comment: You would use Dom mutation to pick up the change rather than setInterval, but I guess each time it should wait to see if there are no other changes to the element within a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use classes to mark the state of the tbody elements.

They could be:

1. "expanded" - Means a tbody is expanded.
2. "loaded" - Means a tbody has been loaded via ajax.
3. "loading" - Means a tbody is currently being loaded via ajax, but is not yet loaded.
4. "permanent" - Means a tr should not be hidden when the tbody is collapsed.

You shouldn't need to register extra event handlers, just have conditional logic in the 
event handlers that checks the presence of the classes and responds accordingly. In fact, you can use the version of the `.on()` function that takes a selector as the second parameter and register a single on-click-handler for the entire table.

```
$('#dataTable').on('click', '>tbody', function() {
    var $tbody = $(this);
    if (!$tbody.hasClass('expanded')) {
        if (!$tbody.hasClass('loaded')) {
            if (!$tbody.hasClass('loading')) {
                $tbody.addClass('loading');
                $.ajax('url', {
                    ...,
                    success: function(html) {
                        $tbody.removeClass('loading')
                            .append(html)
                            .addClass('loaded')
                            .addClass('expanded');
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            $tbody.children(':not(.permanent)').show();
            $tbody.addClass('expanded');
        }
    } else {
        $tbody.children(':not(.permanent)').hide();
        $tbody.removeClass('expanded');
    }
});
```

Note: In this case, you do not need a "tbodyBorder" class. Instead, you would put the border styling on the "expanded" class.

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DmQU8/1/)

Comment: Your bacially saying remove the toggle events and just check the state everytime the element is clicked, Guess thats the best option. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you register a handler for when the ajax returns the data using the [.ajaxSuccess()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) event.

That way you will call your code as soon as the ajax is returned and not have to guess how long the call takes.

Comment: great idea  , it works, but I also need to remove the border when the rows are collapsed so, I tried to attach a click event together with the ajaxSuccess event but no luck ..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe on completion of the AJAX, you can throw in a callback function that adjusts the height for you.

In vanilla Javascript, that'd look something like:

```
function ajax(url) {

    var xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest;

    //put all your try, catch statements in there too

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (xhr.readyState == 4 /* and some other stuff */) {
            callback(someParamter);
            //the callback will do whatever you want, when the code completes
        }

    }

    xhr.open("GET",url,true);
    xhr.send();

}
```

Or, in jQuery

```
$.ajax(function() {

    //all your stuff up here
    success: function(result) {
        callback(someParameter);
    }

});
```